# How to make python script continue after raise statement

Tags: exception, python-3.6

I need to execute my second function cleanup after raise statement incase my else statement is executed in first function

but as this is an exception it doesn't work hence my second function which is cleanup() doesn't work .

Please note : I need to raise exception  in my first function in case the string is not found

Please let me know what can I do to overcome this . Any help is very much appreciated

I have tried if else to achieve this  with raise statement called in else but it doesn't works at all and I am stuck due to this . Please help

```
import os
import re

def validated():
    if 'line is up , protocol is up' in open('C:/Users/diwak/Desktop/1.txt').read():
        print("true")

    else:
        raise ("Not found")

def cleanup():
    print ("cleanup still performed")


print (validated())
(cleanup())
```

My Expectation was both functions get executed :

1) Exception error raised for first function 
2) Cleanup function executed

Actual output :

Program exits out of first function itself in case condition doesn't matches

Comment: I would suggest to look how `try .. except` is working in Python.

Comment: I tried  but unfortunately it didn't worked ...thanks for your help

Comment: please can anyone help

Comment: guys please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is desired (whereas it looks weird):

```
def validated():
    try:
        if 'helo' in 'hello world':
            print("true")
        else:
            raise Exception("Not found")
    except:
        cleanup()

def cleanup():
    print ("cleanup still performed")

validated()
```

Comment: wow , you rock buddy , actually , I was adding else part to except , how foolish of me …………...

Answer (score 0):

```
def validated():
    try:
        if 'line is up , protocol is up' in open('C:/Users/diwak/Desktop/1.txt').read():
            print("true")
        else:
            print("string not found")
            raise Exception("Not found")
    except:
        pass



def cleanup():
    print ("but cleanup still performed")

validated()
cleanup()
```

**I think pass should also work if you agree**